# How to improve the speed of gather() function in MATLAB, or this is an alternative method to transfer data from gpuArray to general array?

Tags: function, matlab

I wrote an algorithm to solve a set of PDE. There are some very long equations in the middle of while loop, and I tried to calculated these equations by GPU for speeding up, then the results from these equations are further employed. It runs successful, however, the `gather()` function takes almost 1/5 of total time (3000s). I tried to use `[dk1,dk2,dk3,dk4,dk5,dk6,dk7,dk8,dk9] = dkfunction(S,T)` in command window, it just cost 0.001s.

I am confused why this code in a big loop performs badly? I want to know if there is a way to speed up `gather()` function, or an alternative function? By the way, the size of array in mex file should be constant or not?

(Note: my code is very long, so I attatch the profiler and core part (simplified) of my question. `dkfunction` is related to cuda).

Profiler for following code operation time:

[image]

```
while t<n  

   %Omitted code for S and T calculation.
   %%%
[dk1,dk2,dk3,dk4,dk5,dk6,dk7,dk8,dk9] = dkfunction(S,T); 

[dkvTdT,dkvTdS,dkvhdT,dkvhdS,dphaivdT,dphaivdS,dkhdS,dkdS,dphaidS] = gather(dk1,dk2,dk3,dk4,dk5,dk6,dk7,dk8,dk9);
   %%%
   %Omitted code to use dkvTdt..... to calculate other variables and t steps.
   %%%

end
```